# How to run RunWorkerAsync on Timer_Elapsed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create an app which should periodically connect to server and request a string from it. This should be done in background in order not to freeze UI while attempting to connect. To implement this, I'm trying to use System.Timers.Timer class. However, BackgroundConnect_DoWork is never called.

To test the concept of BackgroundWorker, I've added a button to the application, which works as expected. It fires BackgroundConnect_DoWork when pressed.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundConnect = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        backgroundConnect = ((BackgroundWorker)this.FindResource("BackgroundConnect"));
        Timer reconnectTimer = new Timer();
        reconnectTimer.Interval = 500;                  //Twice per second
        reconnectTimer.Elapsed += ReconnectTimer_Elapsed;
        reconnectTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ReconnectTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        /*IPInput and PortInput are names of corresponding textboxes*/
        string InputHost = IPInput.Text;
        int InputPort = int.Parse(PortInput.Text);            
        IPEndPoint InputIPEndpoit = IpTools.GetIPEndPointFromHostName(InputHost, InputPort);    //That's working OK when tested separately
        backgroundConnect.DoWork += BackgroundConnect_DoWork;
        backgroundConnect.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundConnect_RunWorkerCompleted;
        backgroundConnect.RunWorkerAsync(InputIPEndpoit);            
    }        

    /* Handler for clicking of ConnectNow button */
    private void ConnectNow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {      
        string InputHost = IPInput.Text;
        int InputPort = int.Parse(PortInput.Text);                           
        IPEndPoint InputIPEndpoit = IpTools.GetIPEndPointFromHostName(InputHost, InputPort);                
        backgroundConnect.RunWorkerAsync(InputIPEndpoit);                                   //This one is executed correctly when button is clicked
    }       

    /*Works OK on button click*/
    private void BackgroundConnect_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
        IPEndPoint InputIPEndpoit = (IPEndPoint)e.Argument;
        e.Result = SemTCPCommandClient.SendReceiveCommand(InputIPEndpoit, Settings.Default.StringToMicroscopeTM4000);           
    }

    private void BackgroundConnect_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some UI update                       
    }
}
```

Comment: RunWorkerAsync should be called from the UI thread. Use a DispatcherTimer instead of Timer (and probably async/await instead of BackgroundWorker). You should perhaps also take care for not calling RunWorkerAsync while another BackgroundWorker is running.

Comment: @Clemens thanks! That worked!

Comment: @Clemens I'm not exactly familiar with local rules of conduct? Should I know answer my own question based on your suggestion? Or wait for moderator to close the topic?

Comment: Just write an answer if you like. A moderator won't do anything automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to move the lines where you are registering to the `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events from the `ReconnectTimer_Tick` method to the constructor.

If you try setting the time span to 3000 and putting a break point in `BackgroundConnect_RunWorkerCompleted`, you will see that it is currently being called once after the first run, twice after the second run and so on.

What does the line `backgroundConnect = ((BackgroundWorker)this.FindResource("BackgroundConnect"));` do? I think you can just leave it out.

If it was't your `MainWindow`, you should also write a `Close` event handler to stop the timer.

Actually, `BackgroundWorker` is a concept from the beginnings of WPF. You don't have to use it any more because there are now more powerful features of async programming built right into C#. It's still working, I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
     private BackgroundWorker backgroundConnect = new BackgroundWorker();

     public MainWindow()
     {
        InitializeComponent();            
        backgroundConnect = ((BackgroundWorker)this.FindResource("BackgroundConnect"));
        DispatcherTimer reconnectTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        reconnectTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500); //Twice per second
        reconnectTimer.Tick += ReconnectTimer_Tick;
        reconnectTimer.Start();
     }

    private void ReconnectTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*IPInput and PortInput are names of corresponding textboxes*/
        string InputHost = IPInput.Text;
        int InputPort = int.Parse(PortInput.Text);            
        IPEndPoint InputIPEndpoit = IpTools.GetIPEndPointFromHostName(InputHost, InputPort);    //That's working OK when tested separately
        //If below is not commented, than BackgroundConnect_DoWork is executed multiple times on each Timer_Tick
        //backgroundConnect.DoWork += BackgroundConnect_DoWork;
        //backgroundConnect.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundConnect_RunWorkerCompleted;
        if (backgroundConnect.IsBusy == false)                 //In order not to call async twice, or it will throw an exception
            backgroundConnect.RunWorkerAsync(InputIPEndpoit);                
    }        

    /* Handler for clicking of ConnectNow button */
     private void ConnectNow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
     {      
        string InputHost = IPInput.Text;
        int InputPort = int.Parse(PortInput.Text);                           
        IPEndPoint InputIPEndpoit = IpTools.GetIPEndPointFromHostName(InputHost, InputPort);                
        backgroundConnect.RunWorkerAsync(InputIPEndpoit);                                   //This one is executed correctly when button is clicked
     }       

    /*Works OK on button click*/
    private void BackgroundConnect_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
        IPEndPoint InputIPEndpoit = (IPEndPoint)e.Argument;
        e.Result = SemTCPCommandClient.SendReceiveCommand(InputIPEndpoit, Settings.Default.StringToMicroscopeTM4000);           
    }

    private void BackgroundConnect_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some UI update                       
    }
}
```

Idea is that DispatcherTimer can be run on UI, while System.Timer.Timer cannot. Some discussion can be found here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77909245-0ecd-4fbd-b831-d82dd6f6edd1/what-is-difference-between-timer-and-dispatcher-timer-?forum=csharplanguage